# Mongo: Get data of two collections - second depending on first one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to display an article and below of that article I want to display some literature data which belongs to the article.
In the collection literature there are many documents, but I want to filter those which has `article_id: article._id`

I believe I think to complicated, but this is what I'm trying to do:

**publication.js**

```
Meteor.publish('references', function(){
    return Articles.find({});
});
```

**Router.js**

```
Router.route('/cars', {
    name: 'main',
    data: function() {
         return {
             article: Articles.find({})
         }
    }
});
```

**template_1.html**

```
<template name="main">
    <div>
        {{article._id}}
        <header><h1>{{article.title}}</h1></header>
        {{article.content}}
        {{>literature reference=article._id}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**template_2.html**

```
<template name="literature">
    Same id: {{this.reference}}
    Now get all item of literature-collection
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
            <li>{{this.title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**helper.js**

```
Template.literature.helpers({
    items: function() {
        return Literature.find({article_id: article._id}); /* this should be the id the first template */
    }
});
```

Guess that could be easier. So my second think was to put the literature-query also into the router:

```
Router.route('/cars', {
    name: 'main',
    data: function() {
         return {
             article: Articles.find({}),
             items: Literature.find({article_id: article._id}) /* How do I get the variable which is needed? */
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a Meteor question, but a Mongo question -- and it is more a question of modeling your data correctly than query it -- such as, why do you have two collections and not one?

Comment: In any case start with -- "how would I construct the query just using the mongshell" ...

Comment: So is the half-hidden comment your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `meteor add reywood:publish-composite`

so your publish function would like this:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('articles', function(){
    return {
        find: function(){
            return Articles.find();
        },
        children: [{
            find: function(article){
                return Literature.find({article_id: article._id})
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And how do I use this in the template? Now I grab the data in the router and put that in a var.

Comment: You subscribe in waitOn function in iron:router, and then use templates like you did in example, all literature concerning article will be on client